# Magento 1.4 Display Individual Product on Homepage

Tags: magento, e-commerce

Does anyone know how to display an individual product listing (As it would be on the product page itself...with buy now button) on the homepage of a Magento 1.4 site?

Answer (score 0):

In the menu *System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages* change the *Default Web URL* to `catalog/product/view/id/XXX` - where XXX is the number in the ID column on the *Manage Products* page.